# White background, black text - the simplest on earth : "error"!

Tags: errors

On my site in localhost, why a simple "error" doesn't pass/permit to do anything at all?
[image: WordPress site "error"]

I browsed the homepage of the project `localhost/creative/`, it's Ok. After then, I entered `localhost/creative/wp-admin` and it goes into "error". Then I tried the homepage again: that's go wrong too: "error".

I retried:

- Clearing browser cache & history
- Using different browsers, etc.
- Waiting for 5 minutes, and then 10...

And SUDDENLY it's back on. :)

But the question is: ***WHY?*** Because, this is not the first time, it happened several times, before. :(

Comment: This is a server/plugin issue; the message is not from WordPress.

Comment: Can you post what's in the PHP error_log? You should also turn WP_debug in your wp_config.php. add this to the top: define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: @DavidKryzaniak: Thanks. I figured out the bug with the debug true, that it's generating by any of three plugins. I renamed the plugins folder to plugins1, and it's live again. I'll consider this solution for next other error in any of my upcoming site inshALLAH. Thanks a lot for your assistance of idea. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the bug with enabling the debug (as suggested by [David Kryzaniak](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31548/david-kryzaniak)):

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Found the bug, it's generating by any of three plugins. I renamed the `plugins` folder to `plugins1`, and it's live again.

#### EDIT

Found a Tutorial on how to proceed on such error from Tuts+, anybody interested in :

- [**Fixing the WordPress White Screen of Death** - Tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/fixing-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death--cms-21008) *by* [Sam Berson](http://tutsplus.com/authors/sam-berson)

There are issues discussed like:

1. Checking Your Plugins
2. Increasing the PHP Memory Limit
3. Replacing the Theme
4. Enabling Debug Mode